# Is it possible to make the grease pencil line art modifier slightly uneven?

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

I'm trying to mimic a comic book's style, which doesn't have perfect lines. The grease pencil line art modifier seems great for it, it already makes the model look better, but I was wondering if there was a way to make the lines more trembly? I went through its properties but I'm still a bit lost.

This is the look I'm going for.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

After the Line Art modifier you can add a subdivide modifier (change Catmull-Clark to Simple behaviour) and a Noise modifier, which can act on Position of the line vertices, and or Strenght (opacity) and or Thickness of the line.

You can even limit its influence to one GP Layer or one vertex group.

[image]